# Minimal polynomial of a linear transformation $(Ax)(t) = x(t+1)$ on $P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> What is the minimal polynomial of the transformation $A$ on $P_n$ defined by $(Ax)(t) = x(t+1)$?

The $P_n$ is a set of polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$, together with the polynomial identically zero.

My solution is quite long. The key steps:

1. $A$ has only one eigen value $\lambda = 1$.
2. $A$ has only one eigen vector $x(t) = 1$
3. Algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 1$ is $n$, geometric is $1$.
4. $A - \lambda$ is nilpotent linear transformation of order $n$.
5. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is its characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^n$

I would like to ask for a verification of my steps and better techniques how to solve such problems. Thanks.

Comment: How would it help here?

Comment: If you know that $\lambda = 1$ is the unique complex eigenvalue of $A$ and you have only one eigenvector, then it is clear that $(A-I)^{n+1} = 0$ and $(A-I)^n\neq 0$. Therefore, your solution is not correct. It must be $(\lambda-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: I've added definition of $P_n$, from the book I study, it is a set of polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$, together with the polynomial identically zero.

Comment: Oh, I see. This notion is not common.